# Passing a string through Android Studios

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to pass a string with data that pulls from a database and I want to echo it into the body of a scrolling activity. I can get the sting to echo in the program I just do not know how pull it into different activities. [This is the home screen of my App I am trying to build.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MCz3.png)This is my MainActivity.xml file and here is **MainActivity.java** code for that:

```
package com.example.it5.foothillers;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements        View.OnClickListener
{

Button button;
Button button2;
Button button3;

public TextView textViewData2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);



        textViewData2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewData2);

        button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);

        button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);

}




private void buttonClick() {

  startActivity(new Intent("it5.foothillers.news"));

}
private void button2Click() {

    startActivity(new Intent("it5.foothillers.sports"));
}
private void button3Click() {
    startActivity(new Intent("it5.foothillers.events"));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button:
            new newsTask().execute("https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt" +
                    "");
            buttonClick();
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            button2Click();
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            button3Click();
            break;

    }

}




public static void callBackDataFromAsyncTask(String result) {
}


private class newsTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line ="";

            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            String s = buffer.toString();
            System.out.println(s);
            return s;

            // return buffer.toString();

        }

        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
            connection.disconnect();
            try {
                if(reader != null){
                    reader.close();
                }
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }





}
// end of private class
```

}

It echos string 's' which is all the text from this link: http://www.komediagroup.com/clients.txt

The content of my news (**content_news.xml**) is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
    android:text="@string/large_text" />
```

and my **news.java** file:

```
package com.example.it5.foothillers;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class news extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);
    ActionBar toolbar = getSupportActionBar();

}
```

}

It calls for the large text string in the strings.xml

When I click on 'News' it opens and my goal is for it to display text from a data base instead of "Test Test Test" pulled from my **strings.xml** which is this block of code:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Foothillers</string>

<string name="title_activity_scrolling">ScrollingActivity</string>

<string name="large_text">

Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 


</string>


<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

<string name="title_activity_news">News</string>

<string name="title_activity_events">Events</string>
```

I wanted to replace "Test Test Test" with the data from the link  from komediagroup

Answer (score 0):

See [this page on Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Building) on Android Developers.

What you want to do is pass a String extra to the called Activity. You do this by calling the [`Intent#putExtra(String name, String value)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method before calling `startActivity`.

Then, in the called activity, retrieve the intent that was used to call it with `getIntent()`, and retrieve the String extra with [`Intent#getStringExta(String name)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Can I see an example of how to use this?